# How to set width of drop down of ComboBox in JavaFX?

Tags: user-interface, javafx

The drop down list of my `ComboBox` expands to the size of the largest element entered in it. However I want it to be a fixed size.

```
---------------------
| Small Combobox | V |
--------------------------------------------
| "Long item 1"                              |
--------------------------------------------
| "Long item 2"                              |
 --------------------------------------------
| "Long item 3"                              |
 --------------------------------------------
```

Comment: tried `prefWidth()` ?

Comment: yes i have tried prefWidth() is setting size of combobox not of its drop down

Comment: do you have a SSCCE - http://sscce.org for your support ?

Comment: Is it javax.​swing.JComboBox or javafx.​scene.​control.ComboBox?

Comment: javafx.​scene.​control.ComboBox

Comment: Even worse: The combo box itself occupies the same width than the dropdown popup (even if closed), although its visuals do *not* stretch, i.e. it stays as shown in your 'drawing', but there will be a large gap to the next node to the right (if used in an `HBox`, `FlowPane`, `GridPane` or `Toolbar` or so)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Use CSS**

```
/** file: combo-size.css */

/** Size the combo-box button. */
.combo-box {
    -fx-pref-width: 100;
}

/** Size the combo-box drop down list. */
.combo-box-popup > .list-view {
    -fx-pref-width: 100;
}
```

*Note: I tested this sample only on Java 8 and I believe the `-fx-*-width` and `-fx-*-height` css attributes may be new for JavaFX 8*.

**Sample Usage**

In this sample, both the combo box button and the drop down list have been sized to the same preferred width (of 100 pixels).

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SizedComboBoxSampleWithCss extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();

        combo.setValue(Font.getDefault().getFamily());
        combo.getItems().setAll(Font.getFamilies());
        combo.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource(
                        "combo-size.css"
                ).toExternalForm()
        );

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(combo);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! The strange thing about it: Doesn't work with `-fx-max-width` and neither does it work without setting the preferred width on the combo-box itself.

Answer (score 4):

The solution (of jewelsea) wasn't working the first time for me, so here is my solution if someone needs a work-around. I just provide a custom cell factory, and I get access to the parent ListView and set the maxWidth in it.

```
combo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>() {

        @Override
        public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> param) {
            ListCell cell = new ListCell<T>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    getListView().setMaxWidth(LIST_VIEW_MAX_HEIGHT);
                    if (!empty) {
                        setText(converter.toString(item));
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Comment: setting the maxWidth somehow didn't do anything for me, but it worked setting the prefWidth ...

Answer (score 0):

```
combo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>() {

    @Override
    public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> param) {
        ListCell cell = new ListCell<T>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                if (!empty) {
                    Label label = new Label(converter.toString(item));
                    label.setMaxWidth(comboBox.getWidth());
                    label.setWrapText(true);
                    setGraphic(label);
                    setText(null);

                } else {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }
});
```

The other answers here didn't work for me. This is a dirty way of doing it but it worked.

EDIT: or you can getChildren() and if(node instanceof Label){} and edit the label from there rather than setting a new one every time in the graphic of the same label

Answer (score 0):

I had problem that combobox size doesn't adjust to updating list, only for the first one. So for me basically works this solution

```
                new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                    @Override public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                        final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                            {
                                super.setPrefWidth(100);
                            }
                            @Override public void updateItem(String item,
                                                             boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (item != null) {
                                    setText(item);

                                }
                                else {
                                    setText(null);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        return cell;
                    }

                });
```