# Set the width of items list in ChoiceBox JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder, choicefield

I'd like to see the list of items the same width like it's title:

[image]

But actual picture is:

[image]

And I haven't found any styles of ChoiceBox's item list in scene builder. 
Is there any style to add in css file to make items list the same width and position?

Current styles:

```
ChoiceBox {
    -fx-min-width: 28px;
    -fx-min-height: 42px;

    -fx-font-size: 16px;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;

    -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-region-background: #000000 /
    -fx-mark-color: #757575;
    -fx-border-color: #C5C5C5;
}
```

Element declaration:

```
    @FXML private ChoiceBox channelPicker;
    private ObservableList<String> channelItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("DAC 1", "DAC 2", "DAC 3", "DAC 4");

    channelPicker.setItems(channelItems);
    channelPicker.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can play with cbMain.setPrefWidth(60), but I don't think it truly achieves what you are looking for.

Comment: I found this. Maybe it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190370/how-to-set-width-of-drop-down-of-combobox-in-java-fx

Comment: Switched to Combobox and the comment above helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a context-menu option to your choice-box css as follow:

```
.choice-box {
    -fx-pref-width: 220;
}

.choice-box .context-menu {
    -fx-pref-width: 220; /* Your width for the context menu background shown */
}
```