# How to set the width of the item list of choiceBox in javafx

Tags: javafx, width, dropdownchoice

I am using ChoiceBox for selecting item from item list. Here problem is that , I can't change the width of the item list.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: not supported - you can try to grab the popup after onShown handler or extend choiceBoxSkin to support it (never tried, though)

Comment: The width is computed automatically, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Cycle of weird ideas: you can add spaces before or after item string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190370/how-to-set-width-of-drop-down-of-combobox-in-java-fx