# JavaFX ComboBox show only arrow

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

I want the following ComboBox:

[image]

to look like one of these:

[image]
or
[image]

The code for the ComboBox:

```
// ...
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.getItems().addAll("Present", "Sick", "Absent");
root.getChildren().add(comboBox); // previously defined
// ...
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192990/11351611 . Should be a solution for your problem.

Comment: @misterharvey thanks for the comment, but those answers were not helpful.

Comment: how should it look if its value is !null?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the maximum height and width of the ComboBox like that

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setMaxWidth(25);
comboBox.setMaxHeight(25);
```