# How to make the minimum width of SplitMenuButton's popup menu not less than the width of the button itself? (JavaFX 19)

Tags: javafx, javafx-19

I want the minimum width of SplitMenuButton's popup menu to be bound to the SplitMenuButton's widthProperty. When the width of the SplitMenuButton changes, the minimum width of the menu also changes. The desired effect is that the width of the menu will not be smaller than the width of the button. How to achieve it?

Comment: `SplitMenuButton` is a bit different, but perhaps you could use a similar approach to this answer for [`ComboBox` popup width management](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192990/1155209).

Comment: Thank you! But using CSS can only set a fixed value, I want its width to follow the SplitMenuButton change. There doesn't seem to be a way to change the width of the popup menu when it is created.

Comment: Provide an [mcve] if you would like additional assistance.